# Match three columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have two Excel sheets.

[image: Sheet One]

[image]

I try to find Column `SY` match with `SYM`, `AC` match with `ACC` and `DA` match with `DAT`, then return the record.

Any one have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a key for each sheet by adding a column concatenating the three others, eg:

```
=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2
```

say in D2 and copied down to suit and then to find the *position* in the 'other' sheet of any matches, something like:

```
=MATCH(D2,Sheet1!D:D,0)
```

copied down to suit.

In effect you are treating the three column sets as single columns, and might choose a VLOOKUP if you prefer.